# Eigen value solution of coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method, code-request, eigenvalues

I want an eigen value solution of following coupled ODEs: But the code showing errors.

```
    gamma = 1.67; ep = 0.01; d = 0.05; H = 1.1; gpara = 0.38;
    {svals, sfuns} = 
    NDEigensystem[{D[V[t, x], t] == 
    Rho[t, x]/Exp[-x/H]*gpara - 
    1/gamma/Exp[-x/H]*(D[Rho[t, x], x] + D[T[t, x], x]) + 
    1.3*ep*D[V[t, x], {x, 2}],
    D[Rho[t, x], t] == - D[Exp[-x/H]*V[t, x], x], 
    D[T[t, x], t] == 
    D[Exp[-x/H]*V[t, x], x] - V[t, x]*D[Exp[-x/H], x] - 
    gamma*Exp[-x/H]*D[V[t, x], x] + gamma*d*D[T[t, x], {x, 2}]},
    {V[t, x], Rho[t, x], T[t, x]}, t, {x, 0, 1}, 4];
```

Q1: I need to find numerical values of lambda (Eigen Values),
Q2: In the above equations gpara is considered constant but it is a variable having 50 rows and 1 column in gpara.txt file, which is in another directory. I import gpara by Import["E\\ ......\\ gpara.txt"] to use in above equations, but its not working too. Please help to get the solution.

[image]

Comment: Start with having a look at the reference page of (N)DEigensystem and the syntax used.

Comment: In your first eqn, it looks like you are using braces "{ }" around your derivatives instead of parentheses "( )".  Also, you will need braces on the right hand side in your `bc=` statement.

Comment: You have a term V[x]*Rho[x] that is going to be an impediment for `NDEigensystem`. Are you sure the term is correct?

Comment: @LouisB, thanks. Now i corrected as you suggested.

Comment: @user21, you are right, V[x]*Rho[x]*gpara has typing error, correct one is V[x]*P0', now corrected. Thanks

Comment: Either you need to delete the lambdas and remove the == 0 from the equations or make the equation time dependent and replace the lambda with D[Var[t,x],t]. Also the last argument of `NDEigensystem` is a number. Please, have a look at the documentation. The only examples with an == are with a time dependent equation. It's all explained there.

Comment: @user21, I linearized D[Var[t,x],t] to give I*lambda*Var, where lambda is eigen value. If i keep time derivative term then how to find eigenvalues, i didnt find any such example?

Comment: @Dainial, can you show me an example from the help page that uses lambda?

Comment: @Danial, in other words: `NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 4] == 
 NDEigensystem[{D[u[t, x], t] == -Laplacian[u[t, x], {x}], 
   DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 0, True]}, u[t, x], t, {x, 0, \[Pi]},
   4]` will give True.

Comment: @user21, thanks for these examples, now i edited the Eqns. and code according to the ref/NDEigensystem:  {svals, sfuns} =NDEigensystem[{D[u[t, x], t] == v[t, x], 
    D[v[t, x], t] == Laplacian[u[t, x], {x}]}, {u[t, x], v[t, x]}, t, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 6]; but still showing errors.

Comment: You have a system with only 5 spatial derivatives, and the highest order ones for two variables ($\rho'$ and $v''$) occur within the same equation.

Comment: @KraZug, yes. These equations come from MHD equations, and are simillar to eqns (18) - (20) of paper "DOI: 10.1051/0004-6361:20034233" for "ep = 0".

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to bring the equations to the standard form and add `Method->{"Eigensystem" -> "Direct"}`

```
gamma = 1.67; ep = 0.01; d = 0.05; H = 1.1; gpara = 0.38;
{svals, sfuns} = 
 NDEigensystem[{-D[V[t, x], t] + Rho[t, x]/Exp[-x/H]*gpara - 
     1/gamma/Exp[-x/H]*D[Rho[t, x], x] - 
     1/gamma/Exp[-x/H]*D[T[t, x], x] + 1.3*ep*D[V[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0,
    D[Rho[t, x], t] + Exp[-x/H]*D[V[t, x], x] - Exp[-x/H]*V[t, x]/H ==
     0, -D[T[t, x], t] + Exp[-x/H]*D[V[t, x], x] - 
     gamma*Exp[-x/H]*D[V[t, x], x] + gamma*d*D[T[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[{V[t, x] == 0, Rho[t, x] == 0, T[t, x] == 0}, 
    x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{V[t, x] == 0, Rho[t, x] == 0, T[t, x] == 0}, 
    x == 1]}, {V, Rho, T}, t, {x, 0, 1}, 4, 
  Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> "Direct"}];
svals

(*Out[]= {0.00592203 + 0. I, -0.500739 + 0. I, -0.813679 + 
  0. I, -1.88774 + 0. I}*)
Table[Plot[ReIm[sfuns[[i, j]][x]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], {j, 
  1, 3}, {i, 1, 4}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Those solutions look very oscillatory except for `Rho`, do they solve the original PDE when you plug them back in?

Comment: @KraZug it looks like you don't trust Mathematica 12 :)

Comment: When it shows these kind of solutions, no I don't.

Comment: Thanks @AlexTrounev. In these equations ep and d are damping factors, when "ep" ="d" =0, svals ={0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}

Comment: @Danial, Do you know what eigenvalues to expect when $\epsilon$ and $d$ are both zero?

Comment: @KraZug, I cant say exactly but eigenvalues should be finite for "ep" ="d" =0.

Answer (score 1):

This should be your equation as given by your LaTeX code (please check):

```
eqn = {D[V[t, x], t] == (gpar[x] ρ[t, x]/ρ0[x]) - 
    (D[ρ[t, x] + T[t, x], x]/(γ ρ0[x])) + 4/3 ϵ D[V[t, x], x, x], 
    D[ρ[t, x], t] == -D[ρ0[x] V[t, x], x], 
    D[T[t, x], t] == D[ρ0[x] V[t, x], x] - V[t, x] p0'[x] - γ p0[x] D[V[t, x], x] 
        + d γ D[T[t, x], x, x]}
```

As I mentioned in a comment, note that there is only 5 spatial derivatives in the unknown variables, and that the highest derivatives for $\rho'$ and $V''$ both appear together in the same equation.

Assume the ansatz of $a(t,x) = e^{\lambda t} a(x)$ for the three functions $\rho, V, T$:

```
eqnSubbed = Simplify[eqn /. {ρ -> Function[{t, x}, Exp[λ t] ρx[x]],  
     T -> Function[{t, x}, Exp[λ t] Tx[x]], V -> Function[{t, x}, Exp[λ t] Vx[x]]}, 
  {t > 0, x > 0, ρx[x] > 0, γ > 0}] /. {ρx -> ρ, Tx -> T, Vx -> V};
```

And then we can solve the second equation for $\rho$, to reduce to just a pair of second order equations for $V$ and $T$:

```
eqnSubbed2 = Simplify[eqnSubbed[[{1, 3}]] /. DSolve[eqnSubbed[[2]], ρ, x][[1]]];
```

Now I have a package for numerically calculating solutions of eigenvalue problems using the Evans function via the method of compound matrices, which is [hosted on github](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod). See my [answers to other questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=compoundmatrixmethod) or the github for some more details.

First we install the package (only need to do this the first time):

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

Then we first need to turn the ODEs into a matrix form $\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{y}$, using my function `ToMatrixSystem`. Note that this is how I noticed that your system was essentially a DAE, as applying it directly doesn't work (something for me to catch and fix, or at least error gracefully):

```
Needs["CompoundMatrixMethod`"]

subs = {γ -> 1.67, ϵ -> 0.01, d -> 0.05, H -> 1.1, gpar -> Function[{x}, 0.38], 
      ρ0 -> Function[{x}, Exp[-x/H]], p0 -> Function[{x}, Exp[-x/H]]};
sys = ToMatrixSystem[eqnSubbed2, {T[0] == 0, V[0] == 0, T[1] == 0, V[1] == 0}, {T, 
    V}, {x, 0, 1}, λ] //. subs
```

The object `sys` contains the matrix $\mathbf{A}$, as well as similar matrices for the boundary conditions and the range of integration.

Now the function `Evans` will calculate the Evans function (also known as the Miss-Distance function) for any given value of $\lambda$; this is an analytic function whose roots coincide with eigenvalues of the original equation.

FindRoot will then find solutions for a given start point:

```
root = FindRoot[Evans[λ, sys], {λ, -1 + 3 I}]
 (* {λ -> -0.342689 + 2.65899 I} *)
```

And we can plot the Evans function to see there are a set of real, negative eigenvalues as well as the complex ones,

```
Plot[Evans[λ, sys], {λ, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

I can't immediately see any eigenvalues with a positive real part, and suspect there aren't any for this case. For your function `gpara`, if you manage to read it in and make an interpolation function from the data correctly, the code above should be able to incorporate that.

Unfortunately my code doesn't currently get the eigenfunctions out immediately at the moment. However, you can use `NDSolve` to get them once you find a root:

```
  sol = NDSolve[Join[eqnSubbed2 //. subs /. root, 
        {T[0] == 0, V[0] == 0, T'[0] == 1, V[1] == 0}], {T, V}, {x, 0, 1}];
  GraphicsRow[{Plot[Evaluate[ReIm@T[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "T(x)"], 
  Plot[Evaluate[ReIm@V[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "V(x)"], 
  Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[ρ[x] /. DSolve[eqnSubbed[[2]], ρ, x][[1]] //.subs /.root /.sol]]
  , {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "ρ(x)"]}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @KraZug for complete analysis. I need to go through the method you suggested. What we need to get correct eigenvalues and corresponding eigen vectors, and also how to check the eigen values are correct?

Comment: Eigenvectors? You mean eigenfunctions? I added an example of those. Note that $\rho$ does not meet the boundary conditions you were trying to impose at either end.

Comment: Thank you very much @KraZug. what should be correct BC for \rho?

Comment: That is up to you to determine with your knowledge of the underlying system. Potentially nothing if you know the other two are correct. I think you can only apply 4 spatial boundary conditions though, due to the highest derivatives appearing in combination.

Comment: Thanks@KraZug. I m using v11.3 and above code is showing errors related to Evans and FindRoot, even after quiting the kernel.

Comment: Thanks@KraZug, its working now, but when i use ep = d = 0, it shows errors and no eigenvalues.

Comment: Both of those limits are singular, they remove your highest order terms (Although rho may become relevant again). You'll probably need to not substitute for rho (use ToMatrixSystem directly on the equations), and drop some boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks@KraZug, Can we solve these equations by this method for V, rho, T using NDSolvevalues with ICs: sol = NDSolvevalues[eqn, 
        {T[t,0] == 0, V[t,0] == 0, T'[t,0] == 1, V[t,1] == 0, V'[t,1] == 0, Rho[t,0] == 0,Rho[t,1] == 0,V[0,x] == Sin[2*Pi*x], Rho[0,x] == 0,T[0,x] == 0 }], {T, V, Rho}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5} ];

Comment: No, my package finds eigenvalues for ODEs with boundary conditions. You should be able to solve a PDE like that just with `NDSolve`, although you will need to only specify the appropriate number of boundary conditions.